# Can't retrieve data from parse.com because it assigns _User as the class name for registrations

Tags: c#, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

Here is my script:

```
void Sync ()
{
    var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("_User")
        .WhereEqualTo("username", userName);
    query.FirstAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
                                    {
        ParseObject obj = t.Result;
        int exper = obj.Get<int>("Experience");
        print ("Success!");
        print (exper);
    });;
}
```

So my problem is: during the signups Parse makes the name of the user class as `_User` and because of the `_` at the beginning I am getting a error at Unity.

Here is the error:

> ArgumentException: Use the class-specific query properties for class _User
>   Parameter name: className
>   Parse.ParseObject.GetQuery (System.String className)
>   User.Sync () (at Assets/Scripts/Database/User.cs:22)
>   User.OnGUI () (at Assets/Scripts/Database/User.cs:46)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ParseUser.Query` rather than `ParseObject.GetQuery("_User")`.

Comment: It wont work because i wrote my own custom membership system. I dont use pre-build parse.com user system.

Comment: That's probably a very important thing you should have mentioned in your question. If you're not using the parse user system, why are you even trying to interact with the parse User object?

Answer (score 0):

Okay fixed it, the problem was parse wasnt letting me take a data from _User class without using ParseUser query as rickrebh mentioned. I created another class called member and put my all data in there(exp,level, id, password, email etc.). Now it works fine as expected.

Ps: You have to change your register system if you are going to create your own class and user system. You cant use parse's built in user register api if you are creating your own user system, its only compatible with built in parse user api. This applies for both login and register.